# R: levelplot vs. contourplot

Tags: r, contour, lattice, levelplot

I want to plot a contour of my data in R.

What is the difference between levelplot vs. contoutplot in package lattice and latticeExtra in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'latticeExtra' package contains none of the functions you mention.

Briefly, 'levelplot' fills in colored squares, while 'contourplot' makes curved lines like a topographic map.

But the best way for you to see is to simply look at and run the code for the examples for the two functions in the lattice package.